# xslt get the content of different child having the same node name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>    
    <List>
    <id_num>1</id_num>
    <car>cars</car>
        <value>          
            <color>green</color>
        <name>nissan</name>
        </value>
        <value>          
            <color>yellow</color>
        <name>renault</name>
        </value>
        <value>
             <color>black</color>
             <name>ford</name>
        </value>
    <value_number>3</value_number>
    </List>

    <List>
    <id_num>2</id_num>
    <car>cars</car>
         <value>          
            <color>blu</color>
        <name>porsche</name>
        </value>
        <value>          
            <color>white</color>
        <name>volvo</name>
        </value>        
    <value_number>2</value_number>
    </List>        
 </group>
```

Using xslt I would like to get the different contents of the childs (color and name) within the node "value" even if it has the same name replicated

the desired output would be this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>group1</group>
<List>
<cars_1>
   <car>
       <color_info>green</color_info>
       <brand_name>nissan</brand_name>
   </car>
 <car>
       <color_info>yellow</color_info>
       <brand_name>renault</brand_name>
 </car>
  <car>
       <color_info>black</color_info>
        <brand_name>ford</brand_name>
  </car>
</cars_1>

<cars_2>
    <car>
       <color_info>blu</color_info>
       <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>white</color_info>
     <brand_name>volvo</brand_name>
    </car>
</cars_2>
</List>
```

when I try using 
 I'm not able to distinguish the different nodes with the different content and, as a consequence their content is replicated

this is the output I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group>group1</group><List>
  <cars_1>
    <car>
      <color_info>green</color_info>
      <brand_name>nissan</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>yellow</color_info>
      <brand_name>renault</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>black</color_info>
      <brand_name>ford</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars_1>
  <cars_2>
    <car>
      <color_info>blu</color_info>
      <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>white</color_info>
      <brand_name>volvo</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars_2>
</List><group>group1</group><List>
  <cars_1>
    <car>
      <color_info>blu</color_info>
      <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>yellow</color_info>
      <brand_name>renault</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>black</color_info>
      <brand_name>ford</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars_1>
  <cars_2>
    <car>
      <color_info>blu</color_info>
      <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>white</color_info>
      <brand_name>volvo</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars_2>
</List>
```

obtained using my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />  


<xsl:template match="/" >
<xsl:for-each select="group/List">

<group>group1</group>
<List>
<cars_1>
   <car>
       <color_info><xsl:value-of select="value/color"/>

    </color_info>
       <brand_name><xsl:value-of select="value/name"/></brand_name>
   </car>
 <car>
       <color_info>yellow</color_info>
       <brand_name>renault</brand_name>
 </car>
  <car>
       <color_info>black</color_info>
        <brand_name>ford</brand_name>
  </car>
</cars_1>

<cars_2>
    <car>
       <color_info>blu</color_info>
       <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>white</color_info>
     <brand_name>volvo</brand_name>
    </car>
</cars_2>
</List>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a trivial task, using either `<xsl:for-each select="value">` or `<xsl:template match="value">`. If you can't make it work, post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. -- P.S. In general, having numbered elements like `cars_1`, `cars_2`, is bad XML design.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I added my xsl file. 
Could you please suggest me a better design for my xml too?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/group" >
    <group>
        <xsl:for-each select="List">
            <cars id="{id_num}">
                <xsl:for-each select="value">
                    <car>
                        <color_info>
                            <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
                        </color_info>
                        <brand_name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </brand_name>
                    </car>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </cars>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>
  <cars id="1">
    <car>
      <color_info>green</color_info>
      <brand_name>nissan</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>yellow</color_info>
      <brand_name>renault</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>black</color_info>
      <brand_name>ford</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars>
  <cars id="2">
    <car>
      <color_info>blu</color_info>
      <brand_name>porsche</brand_name>
    </car>
    <car>
      <color_info>white</color_info>
      <brand_name>volvo</brand_name>
    </car>
  </cars>
</group>
```

which I believe is close enough to the expected result.